# Hive Insert-Only Transactional Tables

Tags: hive, hdp

What are the specific benefits of using a Hive Insert-Only Transactional Table?  Most of the documentation just indicates that if you don't need Delete or Alter functionality, then create this table.  Does this speed up processing?  Reduce Overhead?

Answer (score 1):

Currently, full ACID tables are only supported in ORC file format. Micromanaged, a.k.a INSERT only transactional tables support any other storage format.

So, if you have all your tables stored in ORC format, you can go ahead with full ACID. If you have other storage types, and you need to be able to do INSERT statements, micromanaged tables can help you there.

Also: for full ACID tables, compaction is done by a MapReduce job. You can configure Hive to use the query based compactor for major compactions (as in creating a new base), but minor compactions (as in merging delta files) are still done with MR, and MR only. 
For micromanaged tables, the compaction is query based. So, if you are using Hive on Tez, or Hive on Spark, and you do not want to have MR at all, that is fine. But for full ACID tables, if you want minor compactions, you'll need MapReduce.

Insider note: query based minor compaction for full ACID tables will be supported really soon, and I am pretty sure Parquet is going to support ACID tables very soon.

Answer (score 0):

What you read everywhere is that unlike full transactional tables, "insert-only transactional tables" support data *insert* operations only.

But that doesn't say much. What one wants to know is:
What is a *transactional* insert operation ?

To say that an operation is a transaction means basically that it follows the ACID principles and especially its most important property: *atomicity* (the A from ACID).
In his great book *Desigining Data Intensive Applications*, Martin Kleppmann explains the atomicity property well:

> "if a transaction was aborted, the application can be sure that it
> didn’t change anything, so it can safely be retried.
> The ability to abort a transaction on error and have all writes from that transaction discarded is the defining feature of ACID atomicity."
> [Desigining Data Itensive Applications, March 2017, 1st edition chapter 7, p. 234](https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/designing-data-intensive-applications/9781491903063/)

In Hive, this is done by creating a delta directory for each insert transaction, which keeps the new data isolated until the transaction is completed. If there is an error the directory is deleted, otherwise, it is appended.